# Putting $m$ balls in $n$ limited-boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory

Today I was thinking about this problem:

I have $n\geq2$ boxes and $m\geq1$ balls. I know that the $i-$th box can contain at most $l_i\geq1$ balls and moreover I know that $l_1+\dots+l_n=2m.$

I want to compute the possible different combination in which I can fill the boxes.

Is it possible? Can we at least find a rasonable lower bound? (for example when $m$ is big).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an approach, not a complete solution..
You need the number of solutions to 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i= m\quad \textrm{ with } x_i \in [0,\ell_i] \cap \mathbb{Z}\quad \forall i\in [n]$$
This is the same as the coefficient of $t^m$, in the expansion of 
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+ t + t^2 + \ldots +t^{\ell_i}\right) 
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1-t^{1+\ell_i}}{1-t}\\
&=\left[ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k} t^k\right] \prod_{i=1}^n  (1-t^{1+\ell_i})\\
&=1 + nt+ \left(\cdots\right)t^2 + \cdots +\left[\binom{n+m-1}{m} + \ldots \right]t^m + \cdots
 \end{align}
If you can calculate the rest of the terms in the square bracket above, you are done.

Comment: Chris why should the sum count up to $m$?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Because there are $m$ balls. You can think of $x_i$ in the sum as the number of balls in the $i$-th box.

Comment: Although your answer seems correct, to be honest I cannot get the imposed relation that counts the number of $l_i$ 's up to $2m$. Isn't that a kind of restriction to $l_i$?

Comment: As I have stated in the beginning, the solution is incomplete. The condition, $\sum_i l_i = 2m$ has not been used yet, but can be used later. Although, I don't think it'd simplify the answer much.

Comment: Is it very difficult to have some more term in the expansion of the coefficient of $t^m$??

Comment: And why is this coefficient my solution?

Comment: @Mr.Brown you should probably check what is a generating function and the following link is a good recourse for your purpose http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/gen2.pdf. Also for additional data concerning this interesting object, Tucker's book "Applied combinatorics" (which can be found here https://gettextbook.download/Math%20180/Applied%20Combinatorics,%20Tucker,%206th.pdf) after chapter 6 gives an elegant introduction to the subject with exercises and solutions. Check it out!